# Conditional Rendering React Bootstrap Columns Within Array Map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, conditional-rendering

In my react app, I am mapping an array to bootstrap columns within the JSX of the render function. In my array object there is an attribute called "taken" and if this is true then I want to map different columns than if it is false.

I have tried calling a method to render the output, setting a variable and rendering direct within the JSX. I've tried different permutations of the `${test.datesubmitted}`.

```
            { test.taken
              ? <Col>Taken</Col><Col>`${test.datesubmitted}`</Col>
              : <Col><button id={test.id} className="likelink" onClick={this.handleClickInvite}>Invite</button></Col>
            }
            <Col><button id={test.id} className="likelink" onClick={this.handleTakeTest}>Take Test</button></Col>
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: The issue is that it won't let me render the value test.datesubmitted.

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong . It should be like this . Lets say you have array of object in witch there is one field know as taken .

Ex . `tests = [{taken:true,...rest},...rest object]`

in your react app you have to render it like this

```
    const TestTaken = () => {
return test.map((test) =>
    test.taken ?
    < > < Col > Taken < /Col><Col>`${test.datesubmitted}`</Col > < /> :
    < Col > < button id = {
        test.id
    }
    className = "likelink"
    onClick = {
        this.handleClickInvite
    } > Invite < /button></Col >

)
```

}

and in your render function you can render like this :

```
    render(){

     return(
       <TestTaken/>
       ...rest your code
     )}
```

This is what i added based on what you provided information. If you have any double let me know.

Comment: This gives me the error "Parsing error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</>?"

Comment: Thanks, for now I will stick with the solution I found below.

Answer (score 0):

Tagged template literals is JS, hecen it needs to be wrapped in curly braces. Try this:

```
<Col>{`${test.datesubmitted}`}</Col>
```

Or as you are directly rendering the string value without any concats, better option would be:

```
<Col>{test.datesubmitted}</Col>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the answers above, but kept getting JSX errors, I am not sure if it is a limitation with react-bootstrap.

I managed to achieve the desired result by writing the conditional statement multiple times for each column which is working for me. Don't know why I didn't think of that earlier.

```
            { test.taken ? <Col>taken</Col> : null }
            { test.taken ? <Col>{test.datesubmitted}</Col> : null }
            { test.taken ? <Col>{test.result}</Col> : null }
            { test.taken ? <Col>{test.score} out of {test.outof}</Col> : null }
            { !test.taken ?  <Col><button id={test.id} className="likelink" onClick={this.handleTakeTest}>Take Test</button></Col> : null}
```

There might be better ways of doing it, but it seems okay for the moment.